# Appending a special character with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding

I am returning special characters (specifically `&deg;`) in JavaScript/jQuery, but it is not converting the entity to the desired character in the display. How can I display the degree sign correctly?

It must be simple; what am I missing? I have checked `decodeURL`, but it does nothing.

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rc3ndpxs/)

The HTML:

```
<p>Try to give answer is: </p>
<div id="target"></div>

<p>But should look like:</p>
<div> 5 &deg;C</div>
```

And the Javascript with jQuery:

```
$('#target').text('5 &deg;C');
```

Output:

> [image: Output from the fiddle]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see the interpreted character entity you need to use `html()`:

```
$('#target').html('5 &deg;C');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rc3ndpxs/1/)

Comment: Just a quick note for future reference, this pointed out the nature of my error, but in the end, I used `append` not `html`, because that is what I am actually doing.

Comment: `append()` would work to as it does not escape any characters. I think `text()` is the only jQuery method which has that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#target').html('5 &deg;C');
```

`text` function escapes the `html` characters so you get what you see.